# jinja2: including script, replacing {{variable}} and json encoding the result

Tags: python, json, jinja2

I'm attempting to build a json document using Jinja2 and the document has a nested script. The script contains `{{<variables>}}` that I need to replace along with non-json characters. Therefore, the script needs to be json-escaped afterwards using `json.dumps()`.

`str = '{
  "nestedScript" : {% include "scripts/sc.ps1" | json %}
}'`

The `escape` function isn't enough, since the finished product contains characters that are valid HTML, but not JSON.

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

`str = '{
  "nestedScript" : {{ include("scripts/sc.ps1") | json}} %}
}'`

using some a custom filter or something, but I can't seem to write the include function such that it also does variable replacement in the script. This is my script so far that I am including as a global:

## Complete example

Folder structure:

```
 .
 └── templates
     ├── test.json
     └── scripts
         └── script.ps1
```

template-file:

```
test.json = '{
  "nestedScript" : {{ include("scripts/script.ps1") | json}}
}'
```

Script:

```
loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader("templates")
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=self.loader)
template = env.get_template("test.json")
template.render({
        'service_name': 'worker',
        'context_name': 'googlesellerratings',
    })
```

result:

```
{
  "nestedScript" : "echo {{service_name}}"
}
```

Comment: Can you give a compete example that fails? For your `include()` function to work it has to return JSON.  So if the template is a text file with `{{…}}` place holder that function has to do the replacement and then deserialize it just to get serialized again by the `| json` filter. Doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: It's not actually the json serialization that fais, it is that it is not being rendered using the Context variables provided to the template when calling render. With the current example, any `{{..}}` block would not be rendered and I can't figure out how to make that happen and also convert it to safe json.

Comment: The content of `scripts/script.ps1` is missing from the example and a description of what is wrong the the result, or the result you actually wanted to have. Also the program isn't complete, there is an import of `jinja2` missing, an undefined `self` and the template result is just discarded instead of being printed.

Comment: And there is no `include()` function and no `json` filter in Jinja2 version 2.8. How are those defined?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this in a way that feels a little hackish, so I'd love some feedback. When instantiating my class, I defined a global function called `include_script`:

```
loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(templates_folder)
env = inja2.Environment(loader=self.loader)

env.globals['include_script'] = render_script_func(env)
```

the `render_script_func` returns a function that retrieves the context from the environment and uses it to render the file I referenced:

```
def render_script_func(env):
    def render_script(name):
        ctx = env.globals['context']
        tmpl = env.get_template(name)
        raw = tmpl.render(ctx)            
        return json.dumps(raw)
    return render_script
```

Now, before rendering, all one has to do, is add the context for the rendering to the global `context` object:

```
template = env.get_template(template_name)
template.environment.globals["context"] = ctx
renderedData = template.render(ctx)
```

And when a template uses `{{ include_script("path/to/script") }}` the script is both rendered and then json encoded.

Still feels a bit wrong, but so be it.

Answer (score 0):

Given the (incomplete) example it seems you are searching the `filter` tag.

First the script in a form that's actually runnable and defines a `json` filter in terms of `json.dumps()`:

```
import json
import jinja2

loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates')
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)
env.filters['json'] = json.dumps
template = env.get_template('test.json')
print(
    template.render({
        'service_name': 'worker',
        'context_name': 'googlesellerratings',
    })
)
```

The missing PowerShell script with characters that cause trouble if used as is in JSON (`"`):

```
echo "{{service_name}}"
```

Now the solution for the `test.json` template:

```
{
  "nestedScript" : {% filter json %}{% include "scripts/script.ps1" %}{% endfilter %}
}
```

And finally the printed result:

```
{
  "nestedScript" : "echo \"worker\""
}
```